# Submit buttons' value doesn't pass when used in modal

Tags: html, jquery, forms, django-templates, bootstrap-modal

There is a button in a form (shown below). The button properly passes its `value` on `submit` to the code below when employed in a regular(if you want to call it regular) Django-templated HTML page.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="revoke" value="1" form="my-form">Revoke</button>
```

The serialized data will contain `revoke` and its `value`

```
`$('#my-form').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log($(this).serialize());
```

However, if the form is embedded in a modal as provided by Bootstrap 4, the serialized data has the rest of the form data, but no `revoke`. It would be very nice if the button passed the `revoke` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `serialize()` methods create a string with parameter separated by `&` you can attach value of button as well using `"&revoke=" + $("[name=revoke]").val()` then this will also get passed to your backend page.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('#my-form').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //attch revoke as well
  var formdatas = $(this).serialize() + "&revoke=" + $("[name=revoke]").val();
  console.log(formdatas)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my-form">
  <input type="text" name="acd">
  <input type="text" name="acd1">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="revoke" value="1" form="my-form">Revoke</button>
</form>
```